# Enabling Event Viewer auditing on individual file modifications by Handler ID

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2

I'd like to set up Event Viewer such that I can see who modifies specific files on the system (and when).

I set up a custom view in Event Viewer, but Event Viewer only lets me filter by Event ID.  I'd like to filter by the actual file modified - I'm *assuming* this is represented by the Handler ID.

Is there any way to set up a custom Event Viewer log such that I can see who modified specific files?  Can I do this using the Handler ID attribute?